# How to take one input and a list inputs in one line

Tags: python, arrays, list

For example I have n and m = []

#inputs
7 5 6 9 8 5 6 0
//if we print list then

#output
[5, 6, 9, 8, 5, 6, 0]

here, 7 is the size of list and remaining are list elements.

help me solve this problem....!

Answer (score 0):

To remove the first item of a list:

```py
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
array = array[1:]

print(array) # [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```